# Комментарии на сайте через социальные сети

Tags: javascript, html, авторизация, комментарии

Здравствуйте. Я хочу добавить на сайт возможность оставлять комментарии залогинившись с помощью социальных сетей. Т.е. чтобы пользователь мог авторизоваться через vk/fb/g+ и оставить комментарий который был бы подписан его именем из той сети и рядом с постом шла бы его аватара из той сети. Могу ли я сделать это исключительно на клиенте, чтобы комментарии хранились не у меня в базе а, например, на серверах соцсетей? Не могли бы вы подсказать алгоритм действий? В частности вопрос про вк — использовать ли для этого oauth или openAPI? В чем вообще их принципиальные различия в сфере применения, если меня интересует работа только на клиенте?

Comment: Если именно вопрос о ВК то в документации написано что просто подключаем *openapi.js* и настраиваем его. https://vk.com/dev/widget_comments

Comment: Не только о ВК, про вк только один из вопросов, вопросы касаются также fb, g+ и "Могу ли я сделать это исключительно на клиенте, чтобы комментарии хранились не у меня в базе а, например, на серверах соцсетей? Не могли бы вы подсказать алгоритм действий?"

Comment: https://disqus.com/ авторизация через соцсети. комментарии хранятся не у вас.

Comment: насколько я знаю, disqus не поддерживает вк. или это не так и есть возможность прикрутить?